# How can I delete zero-width space in a Jenkin pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

if you copy a version string from the jenins to use it as a parameter for another deployment, it happens that you copy a zero-width space with it. For example, the parameter system-3.8.1-320-a7fb46d_prodRead​y is passed to the pipeline instead of system-3.8.1-320-a7fb46d_prodReady. This often leads to errors. Now I have tried with
`var = var.replace("&#8203;","")` to remove this learning character But unfortunately replace does not find this string. Is there another variable to remove this zero-width space?

greetings niesel

Answer (score 0):

Please try `replaceAll('\\u200b', '')` instead.